# how to use variables in django fixtures YAML file

Tags: python, django, django-models, yaml, django-fixtures

I am using django fixture, i want to use variable in Yaml file ,Here is an example.

```
- model: taskmanagement.mailsettings
  pk: 1
  fields:
    username: asdfgh
    password: %x
```

I want to encrypt the password. and here i want to use x as a variable.Please help

Comment: You mean you want to replace x with real password, like, let's say, '123456'?

Comment: encrypted password actually.

Comment: You want to read this yaml file and get variable x and from x you can get this encrypted password, right? So where do you want to store this encrypted password? Another yaml file?